# How to fix gettinng ad response error code 1 error?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, admob

Firstly, I am new to Admob. I followed a youtube video and did everything step by step . But at last i am getting error code 1 . I searched some of otheer questions . As the answer i recreated ad units but still no solution.

So please help me..

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DroidCPU"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:shadowColor="#33000000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="1.5"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_top_colored" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="for Android"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Version 1.1"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_read"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style3"
            android:text="Rate DroidCPU"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
package com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

/**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public class PageAbout extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);


        AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("A06424DCD5F3F8D4D9426EC88FACDC56").
                build();

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_read).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getActivity().getPackageName());
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                  startActivity(goToMarket);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://buckydroid.com" + getActivity().getPackageName())));
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
06-20 01:11:46.711 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu I/Ads: Starting ad request.
06-20 01:11:46.743 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
06-20 01:11:46.746 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
06-20 01:11:46.749 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
06-20 01:11:46.769 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
06-20 01:11:46.773 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
06-20 01:11:46.784 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
06-20 01:11:46.788 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
06-20 01:11:46.793 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
06-20 01:11:46.797 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
06-20 01:11:46.801 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
06-20 01:11:46.805 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
06-20 01:11:46.809 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
06-20 01:11:46.825 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
06-20 01:11:46.860 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
06-20 01:11:46.873 15198-15337/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
06-20 01:11:47.288 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for PageAllFragment{e034415 #0 id=0x7f0d008d android:switcher:2131558541:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-20 01:11:47.669 15198-15209/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
06-20 01:11:48.337 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-20 01:11:48.356 15198-15198/com.buckydroid.app.droidcpu W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 1
```

So please help me.